# How to safely delete a socket file descriptor used with epoll in a multithreaded program?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I am trying to solve the epoll race condition problem where an epoll event loop is running and I want it to stop watching a socket file descriptor (FD), but I can't really know after calling `epoll_ctl(..., EPOLL_CTL_DEL, ...)` if the epoll instance actually deleted it, or if it's handling an event associated with the FD, or if it's just waking up the thread from `epoll_wait()`.

I have googled a little bit, and found a peculiar kernel patch adding a `EPOLL_CTL_DISABLE` operation ([here](https://lwn.net/Articles/520012/)). Sadly, it requires `EPOLLONESHOT`, which I don't think is very efficient, since rearming isn't a trivial operation (it requires a search in the epoll's red-black tree).

Thus I was wondering about my own solution. I can obviously just stop the event loop's thread and eventually recreate it later after I'm done dealing with my socket file descriptor, and I can know when the thread is gone by simply doing `pthread_join()`, but let's not be naive, `pthread_join()` will make the kernel release the thread's resources and then `pthread_create()` will allocate the same resources again, which is not ideal as in the `EPOLLONESHOT` case and will surely take some performance penalty.

Now I'm wondering about something else. If I could somehow manually dispatch an event on the socket that `epoll_wait()` will wake up to, I can just deploy any blocking synchronization method after it wakes up to be sure that it doesn't go on further. This way, it will go to the next `epoll_wait()` iteration, where it will realise the socket got removed and no race conditions will happen. To illustrate, something like the following (can really use anything instead of barriers):

```c
/* Obviously, never call the function from
within the event loop, or a deadlock will emerge */
void safe_socket_delete(int sfd) {
  atomic_store(&epoll->should_wait, 1);
  /* This is the function I'm looking for.
  I need to use it to be sure that the event
  loop will go through the should_wait if */
  dispatch_event(sfd, some_event);
  pthread_barrier_wait(&epoll->barrier);
  // we do whatever we want with the socket now
  pthread_barrier_wait(&epoll->barrier);
}

void event_loop() {
  while(1) {
    int events = epoll_wait(epoll->fd, ...);
    if(atomic_load(&epoll->should_wait) == 1) {
      pthread_barrier_wait(&epoll->barrier);
      pthread_barrier_wait(&epoll->barrier);
      continue;
    }
    // handle the events
  }
}
```

Is there any function like so? If not, how can I deal with the problem efficiently?

Maybe I can approach this differently. Instead of dispatching an event on an existing socket to wake up `epoll_wait()`, maybe I can create a new event FD using `eventfd()`, then make it be readable or writeable, add it to the epoll when needed, and tada. Remove it after the fact. I will think a little bit more and maybe try this idea. Of course it comes with 2 tree searches, but better 2 searches when needed than searches when not needed (always need to rearm with `EPOLLONESHOT`).

Huge optimisation would be to always have one such event file descriptor with an `EPOLLET` so that I can simulate events on it and get `epoll_wait()` to wake up. Pros: no tree searches, cons: one more file descriptor per an epoll instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to dispatch an event. Since you are using Linux, why don't you use an `eventfd` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html. Create the `eventfd` and register it with epoll. When you write to it you will wake up epoll and you can process it like any other file descriptor you need to process.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a great idea. I'm modifying my code to do that right now, if it works out I will accept this answer. It's a super cheap solution too.